# How do I use "verily"?

Tags: differences, adverbs

Since verily means truly or certainly. Can I use it where I would normally use certainly?

Like:

> I certainly think that is appropriate.
>
> I verily think that is appropriate.

If yes, are there instances where these are not interchangeable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Verily* is archaic, and nowadays used primarily as a (facetious) interjection, usually in combination with other archaic terms ( *forsooth!* ) and constructions. So while your example is not wrong, you'd be more likely to hear something like:

> Verily! Methinks that is appropriate.

Comment: Does that mean if I can use "certainly", (although unusual) it will technically be correct to use "verily" in it's place?

Comment: @Dian: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I see. Thanks! A couple of friends and I are getting a kick out of using old unusual words in our dialogues. I just wanted to make sure I was using it properly.

Comment: @Dian: Actually the meaning/usage is closer to "truly" than to "certainly".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Okay, noted.

Answer (score 3):

If you were to join up with a local branch of the [Society for Creative Anachronism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Creative_Anachronism) you would likely find people using it on a regular basis. Otherwise, it is probably best if you ignore this particular word, as the use of it will verily get you awkward looks.

Additionally, I do believe that's an adverb so bear that in mind as well as you use it.